# Creating a function in python

Tags: python, function

I am having a little problem when running this function:

```
def upup(palavra): 
    print(palavra.upper())
    return
```

If I try to use the function `upup(ai)`, it shows an error message:

> name 'ai' is not defined

Does anyone know why this is not working?

Comment: have you defined a variable called `ai`? Or did you intend for it to be a string? `upup("ai")` ?

Comment: It seems that you haven't defined a variable `ai`. try to add '' chars or create a variable ai = 'some text'

Comment: also no need for `return` there, it returns anyway

Comment: I intended to be a string.

Comment: You probably want to pass a string variable of "ai" rather than a variable called ai. Try my_value = 'ai' upup(my_value). Also, your function doesn't return any value but merely prints one. And you can just call the upper() method on your string variable of choice to get the outcome which (I think) you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put `ai` between quotes.

```py
upup("ai")
```

You can use simple quotes as well.

```py
upup('ai')
```

Comment: that was it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have not declared `ai` and assigned it to a value. If you just use `upup(ai)` you’ll get an error.
However, if you assign `ai` to a string, like `ai = “string”`, or even `upup(“string”)`, it should work.